# Can we send xml file through web socket

Tags: websocket, file-transfer

I have read somewhere in google that we can't send files through web sockets but I also read that websockets are using TCP. So I want to ask what had I misunderstood and is there a way to send file through web socket.

Comment: Please refer to exact sources instead of somewhere so we can try to fix the material with the incorrect informatio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File uploads should be possible through websockets, at least in **html5**. One ready-made library which provides some basic functionality is [Water under Ice](https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/waterunderice).

There's [an article on Changelog](http://thechangelog.com/post/1986531993/waterunderice-resumable-asynchronous-file-uploads-using) about it, go and read it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can read file system using File API, then get resulting data to Javascript array/string and then put this content to a websocket message.